# IronSource Integration

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads, ironsource

[image]

[image]

Although I opened a new project from the beginning, IronSource gives the following error and UnityAds does not appear in the Integration section, why?

Android Logcat shows UNITY NOT VERIFIED. When I run the application from my phone, IronSource advertisement appears, but UnityAds is not defined.

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)